# Getting Relative dimensions of a measure group

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, ssas

I need to get the dimensions related to a specific measure/measure group (as similar to "Show fields related to" option in MS excel).

Is there any way to get the list of dimensions related to a measure group in C# using any of the adomd objects?

I am using `SSAS` connection, .NET framework 4, VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

The [`MeasureGroup`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.measuregroup.aspx) class has a property called `Dimensions`, which is a collection of `CubeDimension` objects, each of which has a `Dimension` property which contains the reference to a [`Dimension`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.dimension.aspx) object.

The C# code would be

```
myMeasureGroup.Dimensions["myCubeDimName"].Dimension
```

And to get to the `MeasureGroup` object, you navigate from your [connection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.adomdconnection.aspx) through its Cubes collection property to the relevant cube, which then has a  `MeasureGroups` property which is a collection of measure groups.

Comment: Hi,
Sorry. I cant get that MeasureGroup object. Where it can be retrived from. It is not available in all of my connection objects

Regards,
M. Narendhran

Comment: As I wrote, the connection has a property named `Cubes` being a collection of cubes. And each cube has a property named `MeasureGroups` being a collection of measure groups. What exactly did you not find?